# how to show only the final output on jupyter notebook

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, moviepy

How can I only display the final output and not the entire stdout on a notebook? I'm using moviepy and the stdout takes 80% of the screen. [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In VideoClip.write_videofile, you have option to pass verbose as false, by default it is true.

```
 def write_videofile(self, filename, fps=None, codec=None,
                        bitrate=None, audio=True, audio_fps=44100,
                        preset="medium",
                        audio_nbytes=4, audio_codec=None,
                        audio_bitrate=None, audio_bufsize=2000,
                        temp_audiofile=None,
                        rewrite_audio=True, remove_temp=True,
                        write_logfile=False, 
                        verbose=True, #pass this as False
                        threads=None, ffmpeg_params=None,
                        progress_bar=True):
```

Comment: That was it. Thanks